# In git how can I delete all tags(local and remote) except the latest one

Tags: git, git-tag

I want to delete all the tags (local and remote) in my git repo except the latest one. I have read the posts about deleting all tags but could not find the info about deleting them selectively i.e. delete all tags except the latest one

Comment: There is no such thing as a *remote tag*. There are only tags. You have tags, and Joe has tags, and Valerie has tags, and some guy named `origin` has tags, and so on. You can delete whatever tags you like on yourself, and ask that guy named `origin` to delete whatever tags you like on himself, but it's up to him whether he obeys; and if Valerie has tags and calls up `origin` and gives him *her* tags, well, she probably has the tags you're deleting on `origin` and will just give them all right back! (And that's *why* this matters: the question to ask yourself is *who else has these tags?*)

Comment: Hi @torek, This was very informative reply. I was not aware of it. Few take aways from your answer: 1) Since tags are on specific commit if I commit code and tag it as **feature/1.1** on `branch A` and `merge ` **A** into `master` then `master` will have the `commit` . 2) Joe has pulled master, thus he got the commit and hence the tag as his `local` tag.    3) I delete the `tags` on `origin` and my `local` tags. Joe still has that tag. 4) Q: Can Joe push the tags on remote? 5) Q: If Joe pulls master or any Branch A after I deleted tags on origin will his local tags be deleted?

Comment: (1) yes, (2) ok, (3) ok, (4) yes: Joe can push his copy of the tag, either explicitly or via `git push --tags`. As for (5), the default answer is no, but I'm not sure off-hand what happens if Joe runs `git fetch --tags` with or without `--prune` as well.

Comment: Hello @torek, thank you for the explainations. It was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I found the answer on Stack Overflow itself. Customized it a bit with my needs.

Delete all remote tags but keep latest

```bash
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags `git rev-list --tags --skip=1` | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

Delete all local tags but keep latest

```bash
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags `git rev-list --tags --skip=1` | xargs -n 1 git tag -d
```

Comment: If you are happy with your own answer then you can accept it yourself.

Comment: Since I can delete the local and remote tags except the latest one, which was my requirement, can I accept my own answer? Is that alright?

Answer (score 1):

To delete locally all tags:

```
git tag -d `git tag | grep -E '.'`
```

Note: Windows users will need to replace `grep -E` with [`findstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)

The original solution was found [here](https://isabelcastillo.com/bulk-delete-tags-in-local-git-repo-and-github-com).

Comment: Nice! I've removed all git tags with `v0.0.*` using **git tag -d  \`git tag | grep -E 'v0\.0'\`**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to selective delete tags in the Git CLI. There may be tools out there that let you do this, but I'm not aware of any. You could write a little script that could achieve the desired effect. The below is a snippet of PowerShell that will achieve the desired effect. To run it, you will need [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git).

```
git tag -l | Out-File E:\Git\DemoRepo\tags.txt

$lines = Get-Content E:\Git\DemoRepo\tags.txt | Measure-Object -Line

Write-Host "Number of lines: $($lines.Lines)"

$numberOfOlderTags = $lines.Lines - 1

$tagsToDelete = Get-Content E:\Git\DemoRepo\tags.txt | Select-Object -First $numberOfOlderTags

foreach($tagToDelete in $tagsToDelete)
{
    git tag --delete $tagToDelete
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Found another approach somehow!